Is there a way to add a second principal query without re-creating the whole login configuration?
I am configuring a jdbc-realm as described in the official wildlfy documentation, but with a small difference.
(see: https://docs.wildfly.org/30/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#set-up-and-configure-authentication-for-applications)
When I configured the realm, I left out the part of ther query that selects the roles from my database.
I configured the rest of my system as described in the docs.
I know that it is possible to define a second principal query for the roles, when first creating the realm.
My question is: is it also possible to add a second principal query after configuring the whole system? And what would the command be?
Because right now, I would have to delete everything up to my application domain and re-create it just to add the second principal query.
The first thing i tried was
/subsystem=elytron/jdbc-realm=loginDbRealm:add(principal-query=[{sql="SELECT roles FROM data_api.usr_getprivileges WHERE username = ?", data-source=testfpf, attribute-mapping=[{index=1, to=groups}]}])
which resulted in
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"elytron\"),
    (\"jdbc-realm\" => \"loginDbRealm\")
]",
    "rolled-back" => true
}

I understand that this happened because the realm "loginDbRealm" already exists. But I was expecting that this commad alters the Realm and adds the principal query.
Of course, there would be the option of re-creating everything, which I will do for now, since this is only a testing system that hasn't been developed very far. But I would like to have an alternative solution if I run into this issue again, since the potential for wasting time and creating errors is very high if i have to set up the whole system again.
